# Put GTX 660 in hp pc?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I have a HP Compaq p6-2469ea. And I am looking to add an Nvidia GTX 660 or better to run Grand Theft Auto V. Does anyone know if this possible?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't be? What has your research told you so far? Will this be the only video adapter in the system, or are you trying to add I ton as a second one?  If it's intended to be a secondary, what adapter is in there already?

Comment: I've looked at numerous websites (hp, invidia, and numerous others).I believe my PC has pci express V 2, and the above card is V3. But not being an expert I don't know if that means it will work or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PCI Express x16 will it a PCI Express x16 3.0 card?](http://superuser.com/questions/543163/pci-express-x16-will-it-a-pci-express-x16-3-0-card), [A PCI Express 3.0 Video Card into a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot](http://superuser.com/questions/427196/a-pci-express-3-0-video-card-into-a-pci-e-1-0-x16-slot?rq=1)

Comment: PCIE V3 cards will work **better** on a V3 motherboard, but will also work fine on a V2 motherboard.  I know because I have that configuration at the moment. I have an Intel H57 motherboard with PCIE v2 and a GTX 770 (PCIE v3) and it runs perfectly. So long as you have the full 16 lanes going to the card the bandwidth of V2 is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thought is whether you'll have sufficient power. I put a new card in an HP a while ago, took me a long time to figure out that the power supply just couldn't cut it.

If you haven't upgraded it your power supply is 300 w: http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c03727788

This particular GTX 660 card at Newegg required min 450 w power supply: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130825

After my experience trying to upgrade my HP to be able to play some games, finding incompatibility with the non-standard case size/specs, I ended up taking the upgraded power supply and a few other components and finally building a good new rig from scratch. You might find yourself upgrading one thing after another where it would have been more efficient (and fun!) to build what you want.

Search for Lifehacker's "The Best PCs You Can Build for $300, $600, and $1200" guide for some good ideas on what you can get in each price bracket.

Comment: cheers, not as straight forward as I was hoping then.